# Poll Percentages in JavaScropt

Tags: javascript, frontend

Its a simple poll app in Js. where user vote count and percentages will change accordingly. But  the problem i am facing is the percentages are not updated, lets say total vote is 5 and yes vote is 3 among them so yes vote percentage should be updates as the no votes comes along but it not been updated automatically.

```js
let count = document.getElementById('count')
let ncount = document.getElementById('ncount')

let num = 0;
let nnum = 0;

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  let nper = document.getElementById('per')
  num++

  let total = num + nnum

  let totalPercentages = num / total * 100

  count.innerHTML = num + " " + "percentages" + totalPercentages + '%'


  nper.innerHTML = nnum + num + '<div></div>' + "total vote cast"
})

document.getElementById('Nbtn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  let per = document.getElementById('per')
  nnum++
  let total = num + nnum
  let totalPercentages = nnum / total * 100
  ncount.innerHTML = nnum + " " + totalPercentages + '%'
  per.innerHTML = num + nnum + '<div></div>' + "total vote cast"
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>do you like pizza</legend>
    <div id="count"> 0</div>
    <button id="btn">yes</button>
    <br></br>
    <div id="ncount"> 0</div>
    <button id="Nbtn">no</button>
    <br></br>
    <div id="per"></div>
  </fieldset>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the event handlers as defined by the OP, the percentage updates can be handled in a separate function.

There are a few other updates to the code

- statements should end with semicolons (;)
- variables that are only assigned once should be declared with `const`
- the `<br>` tag does not have a `</br>` closing tag

```js
// const should be used for variables which are only assigned a value once
// every statement should end with a semicolon (;)
const count = document.getElementById('count');
const ncount = document.getElementById('ncount');
const per = document.getElementById('per');

let num = 0;
let nnum = 0;

// update the count, ncount and per displays
function updatePer() {
  let total = num + nnum;
  count.innerHTML = num + " percentages " + (num / total * 100) + '%';
  ncount.innerHTML = nnum + " percentages " + (nnum / total * 100) + '%';
  per.innerHTML = (nnum + num) + "<br>total vote cast";
}

// count each button click and call the updatePer function
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  num++;
  updatePer();
})

document.getElementById('Nbtn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  nnum++;
  updatePer();
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>do you like pizza</legend>
    <div id="count"> 0</div>
    <button id="btn">yes</button>
    <br>
    <div id="ncount"> 0</div>
    <button id="Nbtn">no</button>
    <br>
    <div id="per"></div>
  </fieldset>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const poll = document.getElementById("poll");
// counts is an object literal which has two properties - yes and no
// yes and no are objects with an element and a count value
// these are used to keep track of the counts and update the corresponding element
const counts = {
  yes: {
    el: document.getElementById('yes-count'),
    value: 0
  },
  no: {
    el: document.getElementById('no-count'),
    value: 0
  }
};

const percentage = document.getElementById("percentage");

// get all the clicks in the poll
poll.addEventListener("click", evt => {
  // get the id of the button that was clicked
  if (evt.target.tagName === "BUTTON") {
    const id = evt.target.id;
    // remove '-btn' from the id
    const count = id.replace('-btn', '');
    // make sure the id is a property name
    if (typeof counts[count] === "object") {
      // get the counts object
      const counter = counts[count];
      // update the counter
      counter.value++;
      // update the display
      counter.el.textContent = counter.value;
      // update the percentage
      percentage.textContent = ((counts.yes.value / (counts.yes.value + counts.no.value) * 100.0)).toFixed(2) + '%';
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<fieldset id="poll">
  <legend>do you like pizza</legend>
  <output id="yes-count"> 0</output>
  <button id="yes-btn">yes</button>
  <br>
  <output id="no-count"> 0</output>
  <button id="no-btn">no</button>
  <br>
  <p>Percentage of people that like pizza <output id="percentage"></output></p>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: so in your code, if no vote is 12 and yes vote is 3 among i5 votes yet people likes pizza!! can you find the fault in my code?

Comment: Each of your event handlers updates a different percentage display. Maybe change it so there is a single percent display?

Comment: question is how, been thinking a lot but no solution

Comment: I posted another answer, I hope it helps